# Gimp- How can I use a script (``solid-noise``) inside another script?

Tags: gimp, script-fu, python-fu

I want to create a script that call a set of other scripts and run them with specific parameters. Specifically for now, I want to run the `solid-noise` cloud rendered. I created a script and I call the `solid-noise` script using

```
gimp.pdb.plug_in_solid_noise (RUN_INTERACTIVE,image, drawble, FALSE,FALSE,1,8,10,10)
```

Which does absolutely nothing. There isn't even an error message.

So how can I make this work?

Comment: I'm not a Python expert, but in other scripts I've seen calling pdb.plug_in_solid_noise without prepend "gimp.". Have you got errors in python console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using python-fu you don't have to care about run-mode: [link](http://gimpbook.com/scripting/slides/pdb-to-python3.html)
Simply avoid to write it. [Here](http://gimpbook.com/scripting/) I found the most complete documentation about python-fu, maybe it would be useful to you too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the general case, but in my case, I need to call the `solid-noise` plug in (in python, `solid_noise`) without the `run-mode`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using script-fu and than `img` and `drawble` are defined (and using 0 for Run Mode Interactive), this should work:

```
(plug-in-solid-noise 0 image drawble FALSE FALSE 1 8 10 10)
```

Perhaps the documentation lacks, but you can open the `script-fu console` (Filters -> Script-Fu -> Console) and searching for the available functions using the `Browse...` button. Here you can find the parameters to be used, for example:

[image]

Comment: The question was very generic and tagged with script-fu tag, and my answer seems pertinent to me, I'd be grateful for any feedback or criticism that I can learn from or use to help me improve my answer.